# write condition statements in a sharepoint SPListItemCollection before binding the method to asp.net repeater

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

My situation is like this:

I have a function that returns a value as SPListItemCollection and I bind this function to a repeater.
My problem is how can I do some conditional formatting before the return value?

```
SPListItemCollection GetListItems()
{
SPWeb curWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
string siteUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
SPListItemCollection curItems = GetDep(ListName, department);
// write condition here so that it checks if the item count is higher or 
//lower than a specified number.

return curItems;
}
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: Formatting is a matter of rendering, not of the data used for rendering. It doesn't matter whether you use Sharepoint, XML or Datatables. Why do you mention Sharepoint at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not 100% sure what you want to do before the return. If you only want to check if the resultItem.Count is bigger then 100 for example, you can do this:

```
    SPListItemCollection GetListItems()
    {
        SPWeb curWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
        string siteUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
        SPListItemCollection curItems = GetDep(ListName, department);

        if (curItems.Count > 100)
        {
            // change the items or do whatever you want. after that, return:
            foreach(SPListItem item in curItems)
            {
                //format/change
            }
            return curItems;
        }
        // return, without any changes
        return curItems;
    }
```

Comment: Ok let me explain it better. Suppose that the field "Deparment" contains more then 10 items from the same the same department like IT, HR etc, I want to display 10 items only that match the query and then show a message that there are more items to view. This can be a link where once you click on it, it redirects to the list. I hope this explains it a little bit better. Thanks for your previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try smth like

```
    SPListItemCollection GetListItems()
    {
    SPWeb curWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
    string siteUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
    SPListItemCollection curItems = GetDep(ListName, department);

        var itemsForDepartment = curItems.GetDataTable().Rows.Where(r => r["Department"] == department); // you can try to do this is caml too 
        if(itemsForDepartment.Count > itemCount) {
         // insert the "show me more" link
        } 
    var itemsForDepartment = itemsForDepartment.Take(itemCount); 
    // bind itemsForDepartment to a Repeater
    return curItems;
    }
```

I have not compiled this code so you will have to correct some syntax mistakes ;)

Comment: Hi Maks thanks a lot for your answer. I am sorry to be putting it like this in bits and pieces and I thought it was going to be easy, but this is my situation. I have the list and I want to display items based on filter "Department". Now, the user has to specify how many items wants to see from a specific department. If the user specifies 10, then only 10 are displayed and a link which will send the user to view the entire list. So these items are displayed in a repeater. I hope this will explain it better what I want to achieve.

Comment: OK then. I assume you have some controls on the user interface that collect the following arguments: department, max count of items to return, lets say they are dropdown lists that have some values you can predefine outside of the scope of this question. let me update my answer above